# How do you make a css tiled / repeated background stay sharp on a retina screen?

Tags: iphone, css, safari

On the web page, I'm scaling all of my images by 50% with CSS to make them look sharp on retina screens but that doesn't work for tiled images, there seems to be no way to scale a tile background image so that it will be sharp and not doubled sized on the retina screens. Sorry if this question is confusing.

Comment: instead of scaling the images per css, have you tried to use images that have already the right size and quality?

Comment: It's not about the files themselves, retina screens scale images 2x so if your are displaying them at 50% then it looks fine other wise it looks blurry.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Setting [`background-size: 150px 150px;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-background-20020802/#background-size0) for a 300x300 background image seems to do the trick. Note that `background-size: 50%;` will *not* do what you might expect, as it sets the width and height to 50% of the parent container.

Comment: I was having this issue and I applied the background-size and it works. Is it a bug?

Comment: @ChimKan: No, it's because of the way Retina displays treat pixel sizes. This is to make web pages not designed for high PPI displays readable. For example 9px text would look like 4.5px text on a regular display, only sharper.

Answer (score -7):

I haven't worked with Retina displays, but I would imagine it would be better to create an alternate background image with higher resolution for them.

Comment: An alternate image doesn't help, it just scales that image 2x and looks blurry.

Comment: You make it the size that you need in Photoshop. You don't scale it at all. That's the point of producing a unique image in the first place. That way you can keep it scaled 100%.

Comment: Ryan, iPhone does the scaling itself. See this article: http://weedygarden.net/2010/10/retina-display-and-css-background-images/